# CUDA out of memory error when calling PyTorch train script in a loop from another python script

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to run the same pytorch training script with different arguments (argparse) from another python script. I'm using `os.system()` for the same.

Here's what I'm trying to do -

`train.py` = > the script which contains the train-loop.

`runner.py` => the file which runs the train script in a loop.

```
# runner.py
for hp in hyperparams:
    os.system(f"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python train.py --arg1 hp")
```

A few models get trained but I eventually end up getting a CUDA out of memory error. For instance, if there were 10 models, it will successfully train 8 and then give a CUDA error for 9 and 10.

My guess is that the GPU memory is not being cleared after every loop. What can I do to mitigate this?

Comment: Try `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` between each run. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`torch.cuda.empty_cache()` along with deleting the models helped.